# UWP Application screen gets stuck on the white Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using  .net frameWork where I am using UWP. and I created A Application with Help of XAML and C# in uwp.
My Problem is After Debugging Application When Application launch then on just click my Application stuck with white screen . while background activity since work like time .

**XAML -**

```
 <ContentDialog x:Name="dialogHotlistEntry" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="500" PrimaryButtonText="View" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel" PrimaryButtonClick="DialogHotlistEntry_ViewButtonClick" SecondaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource cdSecondaryButtonStyle}" PrimaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource cdSubmitButtonStyle}">
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="450" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtHotlistMsg" xml:space="preserve" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource cdOrderSubmittedTextBlock}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtTMRMsg" xml:space="preserve" Style="{StaticResource cdOrderSubmittedTextBlock}" Margin="0,15,0,0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
```

**C#**

```
 private async void ShowCount()
    {
        txtHotlistMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        txtHotlistMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    string msg = "You have 10 item(s) waiting on  List";
                    dialogHotlistEntry.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    txtTMRMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    txtHotlistMsg.Text = msg;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    await dialogHotlistEntry.ShowAsync();                    
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                
                       
    }
```

On application launch I set a content dialog for showing notification .
Is this problem  due to Content Dialog ? OR What's reason behind this ?
How can I solve this ?

Thank You

Best Regards

Comment: You could make a very simple test to narrow down the issue. Just remove the content Dialog and to see if your app could work correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT yes it is due to content Dialog,when I tried with remove content dialog then it is properly work

Comment: Could you please tell me why you want to show that content dialog? I'd recommend you to call the show() method in the loaded event of the main page.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Used Content dialog for showing the notification which is necessary for us.  And also tried show() method in the loaded event of the main page but it is giving same response .
Do you have any other solution???

Comment: It will be better if you could share the code snippet Content dialog that you are using and how did you call it from the mainpage.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Hey, Sorry for Delay. I am edited the code. please can you review this ?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I have also same issue.

Comment: I tried your code, it works when I'm calling this code from the Loaded event. The content dialog will show correctly when the MainPage is loaded. Would you like to share a little bit more code about how you call the `ShowCount()` method in the MainPage?